# How to sort picklist in Primefaces alphabetically by default?

Tags: jsf, sorting, primefaces

I need to sort my choices in picklist alphabetically by default.

How can it be done in my JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primefaces Picklist component does not have an "order" attribute, so you can't accomplish this in View (your jsf page).

However you can sort your list on managed bean side. This is from the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf)

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{pickListBean.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
```

The following is from the bean

```
List<String> citiesSource = new ArrayList<String>();  
List<String> citiesTarget = new ArrayList<String>();  

citiesSource.add("Istanbul");  
citiesSource.add("Ankara");  
citiesSource.add("Izmir");  
citiesSource.add("Antalya");  
citiesSource.add("Bursa");  

cities = new DualListModel<String>(citiesSource, citiesTarget);
```

If you sort your "source" before initializing DualListModel, you can see a sorted list on your picklist component

```
List<String> sortedCities = Collections.sort(citiesSource);
cities = new DualListModel<String>(sortedCities , citiesTarget);
```

Comment: *you cannot do this on jsf side* you meant that you can't accomplish this in View without executing a method on server side, right?

Comment: This only sorts the initial view.  As items are moved between the source and target lists on the client they will not maintain their sorting.